# MongoDB - NodeJs - remove multiple Object elements from an array, based on another array

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query

My mongodb collection "team" with a field "members" is an array of mongo Objects. I would like to send 1 request to remove multiple members based on an array of user id's

The the "team" document looks like this:

```
"team": {
    "_id": "5defd67ae1536477ef4ce92b",
    "name": "foo",
    "created_by": "5da830b4b693172577d6fdf2",
    "members": [
        {
            "user": "5d7a59e6eb0aa86571f057fe",
            "added_by": "5da830b4b693172577d6fdf2",
            "insertion_date": "2019-12-10T17:31:38.686Z"
        },
        {
            "user": "5da718d16b32b5b9f314cb05",
            "added_by": "5da830b4b693172577d6fdf2",
            "insertion_date": "2019-12-10T17:31:38.686Z"
        },
        {
            "user": "5da5e18a12f3d74b69660b07",
            "added_by": "5da830b4b693172577d6fdf2",
            "insertion_date": "2019-12-10T17:31:38.686Z"
        },
        {
            "user": "5da6fb16fa8262371f504c1b",
            "added_by": "5da830b4b693172577d6fdf2",
            "insertion_date": "2019-12-10T17:31:38.686Z"
        }
    ],
    "creation_date": "2019-12-10T17:31:38.686Z"
}
```

I would like to be able to create 1 update request to $pull several "members" based on a list of "user" id's e.g. `removeMemberList = ["5d7a59e6eb0aa86571f057fe", "5da718d16b32b5b9f314cb05"]`

I've tried the following, but nothing updates.

```
Team.findByIdAndUpdate(team._id, { $pull : { 'members.$[]' : { user : removeMemberList} } });
```

Is there a condition such as $pull all elements where `removeMemberList.includes(members.user)` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is the $pull array Update Operator. Find details [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

Your Query looks lilke -

```
db.Team.findByIdAndUpdate(
    {team._id },
    { $pull: { members.$[].user: { $in: removeMemberList }} }
)
```

Now your members array in document shall not contain those members which are in removeMemberList array.

**EDITED:**
Use Aggregation Instead: Query Looks like-

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      '_id': team._id
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$members', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      'members.user': {
        '$nin': removeMemberList
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        '_id': '$_id', 
        'name': '$name', 
        'creation_date': '$creation_date'
      }, 
      'members': {
        '$addToSet': '$members'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      '_id': 1, 
      'name': '$_id.name', 
      'members': '$members', 
      'creation_date': '$_id.creation_date'
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Tried this. Still nothing. I put "members.$[].user" in quotations, such as below, since node.js could not compile otherwise.

{ $pull: { "members.$[].user" : { $in: removeMemberList }} }

Comment: Please see my Edited Code in Answer. Where i used aggregation to achieve that.